# How to override some properties of TableView.rowDelegate while keeping others default

Tags: qt, qml, qtableview

I'm using a `rowDelegate` to implement variable row heights as follows.  However, it doesn't use the default background colors for selected/alternate rows. How can I preserve all defaults that I'm not trying to override?

```
TableView {
        id: messagesTable
        TableViewColumn {
            role: "severity"
            title: ""
            width: 20
            delegate: Image {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                fillMode: Image.Pad
                source: iconSources[styleData.value.toLowerCase()]
            }
        }
        TableViewColumn {
            role: "message"
            title: "Message"
            width: 300
        }
        TableViewColumn {
            role: "source"
            title: "File"
            width: 150
        }
        TableViewColumn {
            role: "startLine"
            title: "Line"
            width: 40
        }
        TableViewColumn {
            role: "startColumn"
            title: "Column"
            width: 50
        }
        rowDelegate: Rectangle {
            width: childrenRect.width
            height: (messagesModel.get(styleData.row).lineCount || 1) * 20
        }
        model: messagesModel
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

The general rule of styling with Qt Quick Controls is: once you override a delegate, you start from scratch. If the styles provided a `DefaultTableViewRowDelegate` type, for example, you could construct an instance of that and then it would work, but since the default delegates are written inline, you have no way of accessing them.

Comment: Well that's a big shame.  Do you know where I can access the default colors?

Comment: I see a `QStyledItemDelegate`...there's nothing similar for row delegates?

Comment: There's [SystemPalette](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-systempalette.html), but I'm not sure if that will give you the colours that you want. The Desktop style uses Qt Widgets' styling as you might have noticed, but I'm pretty sure you'll have to use private API if you want to use that (for `QPlatformTheme`, etc.).

Comment: It looks I can at least get the text selection color from that, which appears to be the one used for selected table rows by default.  Thanks!